# Average speed if $1/3$ of a trip is taken at $1/3$ speed?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If my maximum speed is $S$ and I make $1/3$ of a trip at $S/3$, and the rest of the trip at full speed, then what is my average speed in terms of $S$?

My impulse to calculate this was (1/3 * S) * 1/3 + S * 2/3 which is 7/9 of S, but this does not match a worked example that I did using actual numbers, so I am stumped how to make an equation for this.

For example, if the trip is 3000 units of distance and max speed is 30 units of speed, then for 1000 distance I go 10 units of speed, which takes 100 units of time, and the for the rest it takes me 2000 / 30 = 66.6 units of time, for a total time of 166.6. Thus, average speed is 3000/166 = ~18. This is different than 7/9 of 30 which is ~23. So, my method is wrong.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: I edited the question to show what I tried which does not work.

Comment: As an nitpick, $2000/30\neq 66.6$.  It is *approximately equal to* that, but not *equal to* that.  You can write $2000/30\approx 66.6$, but equals signs really should *only be used for* **equality**.  To be more exact while still "simplifying" the expression to give intuition like you tried to, you could write $2000/30=66+\frac{2}{3}$.

Comment: if you make $\frac 13$ of the trip at $\frac 13$ speed, that leg takes you the same amount of time at it took to do the full trip at full speed.  Time increase by a factor or $ 1 + \frac23$.  And average speed would be the reciprocal of that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Average speed is total distance over total time. Let’s assume total time = $t$.

We know that distance equals rate times time.

From the problem statement, we have $(1/3)d = (S/3)t_0$ and $(2/3)d = St_1$ where $t_0 + t_1 = t$.

Multiply the first equation by $3$ and we have $d = St_0$. Add that equation to the second and we get $d + (2/3)d = St_0 + St_1 = S(t_0 + t_1) = St$.

And $d + (2/3)d = St$ simplifies to $d = (3/5)St$.

Again, average speed is total distance over total time, so $(3/5)St$ over $t$, so it's just $(3/5)S$.

Answer (score 0):

The average speed is the quotient
$$\frac{\text{distance}}{\text{time}}$$

The dificulty here is to calculate the time.

Let $d$ be the distance of the trip. Since $\text{time}=\text{speed}/\text{distance}$, the walking time is
$$\frac {d/3}{S/3}+\frac{2d/3}S=\frac53d/S$$

Can you finish?

Comment: Okay, you seem to be saying it should be 3/5 which seems right. It's kind of funny two other people posted incorrect answers (now deleted). Deceptively hard problem.